# Fast way to calculate value in cell based on value in previous row (data.table)

Tags: r, rolling-computation, accumulate

Say I have the following dataset `dt` and a constant `constant`.

```
dt <- structure(list(var1 = c(-92186.7470607738, -19163.5035325072, 
                              -18178.8396858014, -9844.67882723287, -16494.7802822178, -17088.0576319257
), var2 = c(-3.12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                   "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

constant <- 608383

print(dt)
         var1  var2
1: -92186.747 -3.12
2: -19163.504    NA
3: -18178.840    NA
4:  -9844.679    NA
5: -16494.780    NA
6: -17088.058    NA
```

The value of `var2` depends on the value of the previous row, like so

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
  prev <- dt[(i-1),]
  dt[i, var2 := prev$var2 - var1/constant]
}

print(dt)
         var1      var2
1: -92186.747 -3.120000
2: -19163.504 -3.088501
3: -18178.840 -3.058620
4:  -9844.679 -3.042439
5: -16494.780 -3.015326
6: -17088.058 -2.987238
```

Though this for loop provides the desired output, it is very slow on a big dataset. Is there a faster way to achieve this output? Preferably using `data.table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `accumulate` function from `purrr` package in case you were interested. In this solution `.y` represents the current value of `var1` that we would like to iterate over and `.x` represents the accumulated value that we calculate and put in `var2` column. As you might have noticed I excluded the first value of `var1` as it we don't apply our formula on it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dt %>%
  mutate(var2 = accumulate(var1[-1], .init = var2[1], ~ .x - .y /constant))


         var1      var2
1: -92186.747 -3.120000
2: -19163.504 -3.088501
3: -18178.840 -3.058620
4:  -9844.679 -3.042439
5: -16494.780 -3.015326
6: -17088.058 -2.987238
```

Answer (score 2):

BaseR variant of above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67708177/2884859) proposed by dear friend (which you can use easily in your `data.table` syntax)

```r
dt <- structure(list(var1 = c(-92186.7470607738, -19163.5035325072, 
                              -18178.8396858014, -9844.67882723287, -16494.7802822178, -17088.0576319257
), var2 = c(-3.12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", 
                                                   "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

dt
#>         var1  var2
#> 1 -92186.747 -3.12
#> 2 -19163.504    NA
#> 3 -18178.840    NA
#> 4  -9844.679    NA
#> 5 -16494.780    NA
#> 6 -17088.058    NA
constant <- 608383
Reduce(function(.x, .y) .x - .y /constant , dt$var1[-1], init = dt$var2[1], accumulate = T)
#> [1] -3.120000 -3.088501 -3.058620 -3.042439 -3.015326 -2.987238
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>