# Fast way to calculate values in cells based on values in previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr, rolling-computation

I wish to have a fast way to deal with rowwise calculations where values of cells depend on values in previous rows of different columns, prefering vectorization over looping through individual rows (follow-up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707005/fast-way-to-calculate-value-in-cell-based-on-value-in-previous-row-data-table)).

Say I have the following dataset `dt` and a `constant` (loaded libraries are `data.table`, `dplyr` and `purrr`)

```
dt <- structure(list(var1 = c(-92186.7470607738, -19163.5035325072, 
-18178.8396858014, -9844.67882723287, -16494.7802822178, -17088.0576319257
), var2 = c(-3.12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var3 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

constant <- 608383


print(dt)
         var1  var2 var3
1: -92186.747 -3.12    1
2: -19163.504    NA   NA
3: -18178.840    NA   NA
4:  -9844.679    NA   NA
5: -16494.780    NA   NA
6: -17088.058    NA   NA
```

The fast, vectorized equivalent of

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
  prev <- dt[(i-1),]
  dt[i, var2 := prev$var2 - var1/constant]
}
```

would be

```
dt %>%
  mutate(var2 = accumulate(var1[-1], .init = var2[1], ~ .x - .y /constant))
```

But what if I want to include more columns in the calculation? In this example `var3`, but in the real dataset there are >10 columns. I wish the solution to keep that into account. Example for loop (desired output):

```
for(i in 2:nrow(dt)){
  prev <- dt[(i-1),]
  dt[i, var2 := prev$var2 + prev$var3 - var1/constant]
  dt[i, var3 := prev$var1 + 0.1 * var2/constant]
}
print(dt)

         var1          var2      var3
1: -92186.747 -3.120000e+00      1.00
2: -19163.504 -2.088501e+00 -92186.75
3: -18178.840 -9.218881e+04 -19163.52
4:  -9844.679 -1.113523e+05 -18178.86
5: -16494.780 -1.295311e+05  -9844.70
6: -17088.058 -1.393758e+05 -16494.80
```

Comment: Though I have included a baseR way that can be emulated for any number of variables, you may still have a [reference on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796202/2884859)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though [My friend's output/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68364377/2884859) is fabulous, but since we cannot have two input vectors in baseR's `Reduce()` so I used this trick-

- Generated fresh values of `var1` in `data.frame()` inside the `Reduce()`
- Where you want to use current values of `var1` use `.y`
- where previous values were to be used use `.x$var1` instead.
- used formula where I'd require to use current generated value of any variable.
- rest is pretty clear I think.
- `accumulate = TRUE` is obvious becuase you want all intermediate values.
- Since output here will be a list, that is `rbind` using `do.call`

In base R you can do

```r
do.call(rbind, Reduce(function(.x, .y) {data.frame(var1 = .y,
                            var2 = .x$var2 + .x$var3 -.y/constant,
                            var3 = .x$var1 + 0.1 * (.x$var2 + .x$var3 -.y/constant)/constant)}, 
       dt$var1[-1], 
       init =  data.frame(var1 = dt$var1[1], var2 = -3.12, var3 = 1),
       accumulate = TRUE))

        var1          var2      var3
1 -92186.747 -3.120000e+00      1.00
2 -19163.504 -2.088501e+00 -92186.75
3 -18178.840 -9.218881e+04 -19163.52
4  -9844.679 -1.113523e+05 -18178.86
5 -16494.780 -1.295311e+05  -9844.70
6 -17088.058 -1.393758e+05 -16494.80
```

which can be emulated in tidyverse/purrr as follows

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(dt$var1[-1], .init = data.frame(var1 = dt$var1[1], var2 = -3.12, var3 = 1), 
           ~ data.frame(var1 = .y,
                        var2 = .x$var2 + .x$var3 -(.y/constant),
                        var3 = .x$var1 + 0.1 * (.x$var2 + .x$var3 -(.y/constant))/constant)) %>% map_df(~.x)

        var1          var2      var3
1 -92186.747 -3.120000e+00      1.00
2 -19163.504 -2.088501e+00 -92186.75
3 -18178.840 -9.218881e+04 -19163.52
4  -9844.679 -1.113523e+05 -18178.86
5 -16494.780 -1.295311e+05  -9844.70
6 -17088.058 -1.393758e+05 -16494.80
```

Comment: Awesome base R solution!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks alot (again) for your help :)

Comment: Can a method like this be followed with two defined input vectors? For example a fully filled column ```var4```

Comment: @maarvd, yes why not?  see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796202/2884859) proposed on another question.

Answer (score 4):

Another option using Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('List func(NumericVector var1, double c, double v2, double v3) {
    int n = var1.size();
    NumericVector var2(n);
    NumericVector var3(n);
    
    var2[0] = v2;
    var3[0] = v3;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        var2[i] = var2[i-1] + var3[i-1] - var1[i]/c;
        var3[i] = var1[i-1] + 0.1 * var2[i]/c;
    }
    
    List ret;
    ret["var2"] = var2;
    ret["var3"] = var3;
    return ret;
}')
dt[, c("var2", "var3") := func(var1, constant, var2[1L], var3[1L])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting solution! I was not aware of this package, integration of R with C++ seems very useful when wanting fast code

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution in base R you could use:

```
do.call(rbind, Reduce(function(x, y) {
  data.frame(var1 = dt$var1[y], 
             var2 = x[["var2"]] + x[["var3"]] - (dt$var1[y] / constant),
             var3 = dt$var1[y - 1] + 0.1 * ((x[["var2"]] + x[["var3"]] - (dt$var1[y] / constant)) / constant))
}, init = data.frame(var1 = dt$var1[1], var2 = -3.12, var3 = 1), 2:nrow(dt), accumulate = TRUE))

        var1          var2      var3
1 -92186.747 -3.120000e+00      1.00
2 -19163.504 -2.088501e+00 -92186.75
3 -18178.840 -9.218881e+04 -19163.52
4  -9844.679 -1.113523e+05 -18178.86
5 -16494.780 -1.295311e+05  -9844.70
6 -17088.058 -1.393758e+05 -16494.80
```

I think you can use the following solution. Here are some notes on how it works:

- In this question we need to fill 2 vectors of length 6, two of which are already specified through `.init` argument and contrary to the previous question we are populating two variables so we need to create a `tibble` and start from there
- There remains 5 other varlues to populate as we supplied `.init` the first and second vector should be of equal length, otherwise the second vector should be one element shorter than the first one (without `.init`)
- Since we are dealing with actual and previous value of `var1`, I decided to use it twice each time omitting first and last value respectively, so that for example in calculating `var3` where you need `prev$var1` it is actually the first value of the second variable `var1[-n()]`
- `..1` is always the accumulated/previous value, here since we got two `var2` and `var3` we can subset it with `$` to specify which one we are referring to
- `..2` is the next value in sequence from first vector `.x` in general and `var1[-1]` here and `..3` is the next value in sequence from second vector `.y` in general and `var1[-n()]` here

If these notes were not suffice I would be glad to explain more.

```
library(purrr)

dt[,1] %>%
  bind_cols(dt %>%
              mutate(output = accumulate2(var1[-1], var1[-n()], .init = tibble(var2 = -3.12, var3 = 1), 
                                          ~ tibble(var2 = (..1$var2 + ..1$var3 - (..2/constant)),
                                                   var3 = ..3 + 0.1 * ((..1$var2 + ..1$var3 - (..2/constant)) /constant)))) %>%
              select(output) %>%
              unnest(output))

         var1          var2      var3
1: -92186.747 -3.120000e+00      1.00
2: -19163.504 -2.088501e+00 -92186.75
3: -18178.840 -9.218881e+04 -19163.52
4:  -9844.679 -1.113523e+05 -18178.86
5: -16494.780 -1.295311e+05  -9844.70
6: -17088.058 -1.393758e+05 -16494.80
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer (again) and the explanation. The rationale is clear, but to totally comprehend it I will play around with some different example data.